# Count character per line with Windows CMD

Tags: csv, batch-file, scripting

I have a bunch of CSV-files, where I need to count the delimiter per line to ensure, that the right amount of attributes was delivered. The files look like this:

> Attribute1~Attribute2~0~~~1~1000~Attribute8
>
> Attribute1~Attribute2~0~~~1~1000~Attribute8
>
> Attribute1~Attribute2~0~~~1~2000~Attribute8

The delimiter is `~` (tilde). Do you have any suggestions? It has to be executable from **Windows cmd**.

```
set inputFile=%FILE%
set "searchChar=~"

for /f "delims=" %%a in (' findstr /n "^" %FILE% ') do
    for /f "delims=:" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
        set "line=%%a"
        for /f %%c in (' cmd /u /v /e /q /c"(echo(!line:*:=!)"^|find /c "%searchChar%" ') do
            echo Line %%b has %%c characters
    )
)
```

it just prints the number of characters. I need an if-clause if %%c <> 7

Comment: What is the code that you have tried? & could you please add that?

Comment: set inputFile=%FILE%
    set "searchChar=~"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        findstr /n "^" %FILE%
    ') do for /f "delims=:" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
        set "line=%%a"
        for /f %%c in ('
            cmd /u /v /e /q /c"(echo(!line:*:=!)"^|find /c "%searchChar%"
        ') do echo Line %%b has %%c characters )
 )

Comment: it just prints the number of characters. I need an if-clause if %%c <> 7

Comment: What is stopping you from using the `IF` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough with PowerShell. The code compares the length of the original line to a line with the TILDE characters removed.

This can be run on any modern-day, supported Windows machine from cmd.exe. Yes, it is a lot easier and cleaner if written as a PowerShell script.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "inputFile=.\countds.csv"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '%inputFile%' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "$ns = $_ -replace '~','';" ^
            "if (($_.Length - $ns.Length) -ne 7) {" ^
                "'Length is {0}' -f ($_.Length - $ns.Length)" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

Comment: How do you check if the returned length is <> 7 e.g.?

Comment: @nikoffm - The script is modified to test for seven (7) delimiters. If you want to know which line number it occurred on, feel free to add a counter and increment is inside the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the delimiter does not also occur in quoted strings the following PowerShell script
checks **every** line in the file and uses `Measure-Object` to maintain -Sum, -Average -Min, -Max and -Count of the delimiters.

```
> Get-Content .\test.csv| ForEach-Object{($_ -split  '~').Count}|Measure-Object -Sum -Average -Minimum -Maximum

Count    : 3
Average  : 8
Sum      : 24
Maximum  : 8
Minimum  : 8
Property :
```

If Average, Max and Min are equal all the lines have the same column count.

To be on topic, wrapped ina batch file:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\03\19\SO_55231094.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "inputFile=.\test.csv"

:: clear var with prefix _
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set _ 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%A in (`
  powershell -nop -c "(Get-Content $ENV:inputFile)|ForEach-Object{($_ -split '~').Count}|Measure-Object -Sum -Average -Minimum -Maximum"
`) do if "%%B" neq "" Set "_%%A=%%B"

Set _
```

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2019\03\19\SO_55231094.cmd
_Average=8
_Count=3
_Maximum=8
_Minimum=8
_Sum=24
```